# is transforms working in confluent.cloud(Kafka) to elastic cloud

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, elastic-cloud, confluent-cloud

I am creating the elastic sink connector in confluent.cloud(Kafka). here, if I use transforms, it is not working. will confluent.cloud(kafka) supports transforms?.

Below is my script,

```
{
      "name": "ElasticConnectorTest5",
      "config": {
      "topics": "enterprise.contact6.model",
      "input.data.format": "AVRO",
      "connector.class": "ElasticsearchSink",
      "name": "ElasticConnectorTest5",
      "kafka.api.key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "kafka.api.secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "connection.url": "url",
      "connection.username": "**********",
      "connection.password": "*********",
      "type.name": "_doc",
      "key.ignore": "false",
      "schema.ignore": "true",
      "tasks.max": "1",
      "errors.tolerance": "all",
      "errors.log.enable": "true",
      "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
      "behavior.on.malformed.documents": "warn",
      "transforms": "InsertMetadata,IndexName",
      "transforms.InsertMetadata.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
      "transforms.InsertMetadata.partition.field": "partition",
      "transforms.InsertMetadata.offset.field": "offset",
      "transforms.IndexName.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
      "transforms.IndexName.regex": "enterprise.(.*)",
      "transforms.IndexName.replacement": "es.$1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Single Message Transforms (SMTs) are now supported by Confluent Cloud](https://www.confluent.io/blog/new-confluent-cloud-connector-features-and-single-message-transforms/) (Oct 2021):

> we’re excited to announce that **most** of our Confluent Cloud connectors now support single message transforms, connector log events, and connector data output previews.

Note, there is word "most" in the announcement and [some transforms  are not yet supported](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/single-message-transforms.html#unsupported-transformations):

> The RegexRouter SMT is not currently supported for managed
> connectors.
> A few sink connectors do not support the following transformations.
> This limitation is noted in the connector Quick
> Start for each affected connector.
>
> ```
>     org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampRouter
>     io.confluent.connect.transforms.MessageTimestampRouter
>     io.confluent.connect.transforms.ExtractTopic$Key
>     io.confluent.connect.transforms.ExtractTopic$Value
> ```

As well as some specific [limitations for Elasticsearch Service Sink Connector for Confluent Cloud](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/limits.html#elasticsearch-service-sink-connector).